# Can’t select which OS to boot into on a dual boot Linux Mint / Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, dualboot

I have been trying to install Linux for so long that finally, I've succeeded to install LMDE on my external hard drive.

The problem is when the installation finished it asked me if I want to restart it. I clicked on yes then it says to unplug the USB flash drive used in the installation and click on <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it goes straight to Windows without giving me the menu to choose between Linux and Windows.

I've tried some solutions but they didn't work for me:

- In the boot option I can't find Linux to change the boot order
- I installed easybcd but it only shows me windows like Linux is not installed!

Comment: With your external plugged in, what is the boot sequence in your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: What is the version of Windows

Comment: i have windows 10

Comment: generic usb drive is the first in the boot order

Comment: How did you partition that drive?

Comment: on 3 partitions swap area, boot and the last one I don't remember its name, 1Gb, 8Gb, 400Gb

Comment: @RahmaBegag Try holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + The restart option under the power menu, it should have a "boot options" or "boot entries" or "other operating systems" (i don't remember exactly) option. Is it there?

Comment: I did it but "other operating systems" doesn't show up